# Creating Static Image with Path and Colored Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to produce incident maps from GPS data, showing two minutes either side of the route as a path, and three markers: start, incident, end.  All I'm getting is Error 400, malformed URL.  I've tried chopping and changing, using smaller components of the URL, but its not working.

Any advice on my URL structure?  Am I not encoding something properly?  Anyway to get feedback on which part its choking on?  Should I not be using the Static Maps API?

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?format=jpg&sensor=false&path=color:green%7Cweight:5%7C-21.3322,148.9388%7C-21.3330,148.9402%7C-21.3302,148.9397%7C-21.3287,148.9394%7C-21.3273,148.9393%7C-21.3261,148.9392%7C-21.3247,148.9391%7C-21.3239,148.9390%7C-21.3236,148.9389%7C-21.3236,148.9389%7C-21.3198,148.9371%7C-21.3186,148.9364%7C-21.3175,148.9357%7C-21.3162,148.9350%7C-21.3153,148.9347%7C-21.3141,148.9344%7C-21.3128,148.9342%7C-21.3116,148.9341%7C-21.3103,148.9341%7C-21.3090,148.9341%7C-21.3077,148.9340%7C-21.3064,148.9340%7C-21.3051,148.9339%7C-21.3039,148.9339%7C-21.3026,148.9339%7C-21.3013,148.9340%7C-21.3013,148.9340&markers=color:red%7Clabel:Speed%20violation%7C-21.3302,148.9397&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:Support%20Pack%20End%7C-21.3013,148.9340&key=[snip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the required `size`-parameter is missing inside the URL

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?**size=400x400**&format=jpg&sensor=false&path=color:green%7Cweight:5%7C-21.3322,148.9388%7C-21.3330,148.9402%7C-21.3302,148.9397%7C-21.3287,148.9394%7C-21.3273,148.9393%7C-21.3261,148.9392%7C-21.3247,148.9391%7C-21.3239,148.9390%7C-21.3236,148.9389%7C-21.3236,148.9389%7C-21.3198,148.9371%7C-21.3186,148.9364%7C-21.3175,148.9357%7C-21.3162,148.9350%7C-21.3153,148.9347%7C-21.3141,148.9344%7C-21.3128,148.9342%7C-21.3116,148.9341%7C-21.3103,148.9341%7C-21.3090,148.9341%7C-21.3077,148.9340%7C-21.3064,148.9340%7C-21.3051,148.9339%7C-21.3039,148.9339%7C-21.3026,148.9339%7C-21.3013,148.9340%7C-21.3013,148.9340&markers=color:red%7Clabel:Speed%20violation%7C-21.3302,148.9397&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:Support%20Pack%20End%7C-21.3013,148.9340](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&format=jpg&sensor=false&path=color%3agreen%7Cweight:5%7C-21.3322,148.9388%7C-21.3330,148.9402%7C-21.3302,148.9397%7C-21.3287,148.9394%7C-21.3273,148.9393%7C-21.3261,148.9392%7C-21.3247,148.9391%7C-21.3239,148.9390%7C-21.3236,148.9389%7C-21.3236,148.9389%7C-21.3198,148.9371%7C-21.3186,148.9364%7C-21.3175,148.9357%7C-21.3162,148.9350%7C-21.3153,148.9347%7C-21.3141,148.9344%7C-21.3128,148.9342%7C-21.3116,148.9341%7C-21.3103,148.9341%7C-21.3090,148.9341%7C-21.3077,148.9340%7C-21.3064,148.9340%7C-21.3051,148.9339%7C-21.3039,148.9339%7C-21.3026,148.9339%7C-21.3013,148.9340%7C-21.3013,148.9340&markers=color%3ared%7Clabel%3aSpeed%20violation%7C-21.3302,148.9397&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aSupport%20Pack%20End%7C-21.3013,148.9340)

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I'd read I could ignore that as I was using markers and lat/long, but apparently not

Comment: `zoom` and `center` may be ommitted when markers are present, `size` is always required